# Как правильно получить год из даты sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, дата

Здравствуйте, мне нужно получить разницу между двумя датами с помощью функции `select DATEDIFF(year, 1997-01-01, getdate())`
но функция возвращает не верное значение, плохо отрабатывает функция, которая вычисляет год из даты (т.е. 2й аргумент), если выполнить функцию year(1997-01-01) то она вернет 1905, в моей таблице есть поле DateOfBurn и значение его date (при заполнении я только ввожу "1990-02-02") и есть вычисляемый столбец Age `DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBurn, getdate())` Помогите пожалуйста составить запрос правильно.

Comment: А вы дату `'1997-01-01'` не пытались в кавычки (одинарные) заключить. А то ведь 1997-01-01=1995 и как это преобразуется к дате ума не приложу

Comment: Укажите тип СУБД пожайлуста. В разных субд по-разному. На MSSQL вообще просто `select year(getdate())`

Comment: @nick_n_a У него MS SQL. Только что проверил, на MySQL year(1997-01-01) (дата без кавычек) дает NULL, а на MS SQL как раз 1905, видать число 1995 так к дате преобразует :)

Comment: Чудесно - гадание по типу ошибки))). В MSSQL есть особенность. Если дату передаёте строкой он её конвертирует согласно системных настроек. Надо или правильно выставить в опциях ф-т даты или вручную в sql так: `convert(datetime,'01.02.2016',104)`

Comment: Это конвертируется как 1995 дней с даты '1900-01-01' - это дата '1905-03-21' в 1905 году.

Comment: Целые числа и дробные числа конвертируются как обозначил @i-one ставьте кавычки.

Comment: select year('1997-01-01') = 1997 (MS SQL)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да, действительно нужно было поставить кавычки

Comment: Использовал MS SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нужно передать дату как строку в кавычках

```
DATEDIFF(year, '1997-01-01', getdate())
```