# Как правильно вычислить столбец MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, дата

Здравствуйте, у меня есть таблица Player с несколькими полями, одно из них это DateOfBorn, и у меня есть поле Age, которое должно вычисляться по формуле "текущая дата - DateOfBorn. Если просто написать Select запрос, то все нормально

```
select  datepart(year,getdate())-datepart(year, Convert(Varchar, DateOfBurn, 104))
from Players
```

И если это выполнить просто в запросе, то все вычисляется правильно, но если я подставлю это выражение в значение, которое вычисляется для столбца AGE, то при попытке его сохранения среда пишет, что присутствуют ошибки в этом выражении.
Но если заменить вычитаемое, что бы получилось, например, так `(datepart(year,getdate())-'1997')` то в итоге ошибки нет, и при просмотре таблицы, будет отражено "19".
Прошу помочь написать правильно вычитаемое, DOB имеет тип "date" т.е. мне нужно при заполнении таблицы вводить только с точностью до дня (указывать еще время рождения в моей области будет бессмысленно). Спасибо!

Comment: А для чего вам хранить отдельно дату рождения и возраст?

Comment: Так возраст будет вычисляться. Это сделано для представления, поэтому столбец и вычисляемый.

Comment: покажите весь запрос и весь текст сообщения об ошибке

Comment: По мойму я указал в вопросе что мне нужно. Запрос, который я проверяю указан в вопросе. А в конструкторе для столбца AGE я указываю формулу для вычисления datepart(year,getdate())-datepart(year, Convert(Varchar, DateOfBurn, 104)), но это не работает... Но (datepart(year,getdate())-'1997') работает

Comment: Зачем вы приводите аргумент к типу varchar, если он должен быть типа даты? Какого типа DateOfBurn?

Comment: DateOfBorn типа date, дело в том, что если я не приведу эту дату к строке, то будет ошибка в вычислении даты, вот вам ссылка на мой вопрос по этому поводу http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564092/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-sql

Comment: У поля DateOfBurn какой тип данных ? Если это дата, то зачем вы конвертируете ее в varhar. Напишите просто `datepart(year,getdate())-datepart(year,DateOfBurn)` Если же у вас в этом поле какой то текст или число - укажите в вопросе, какое именно значение там находится.

Comment: [аналогичная проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598271/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82/598480#598480)

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно вычислять год каждой даты и потом считать их разницу. Более точное вычисление возраста это:    DATEDIFF(year,DateOfBurn,getdate())
Вычисляемый столбец с таким выражением работает нормально.