# Посчитать кол-во минут

Tags: sql-server

У меня есть выражение
`CAST((time_in - time_out) as time)`,
где `time_in` и `time_out` имеют тип **datetime**. Выражение возвращает `01:48:00.0000000`.

Как мне посчитать количество минут, чтобы вернуло 108?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью функции [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189794.aspx), `CAST` тут не нужен.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MI, time_in, time_out);
```